# unexpected case, expecting expression error when compiling go

Tags: go

When I compile the following code, it generates

*syntax error: `unexpected case, expecting expression*` at line `*case workerAddr = <- mr.registerChannel:*`

I do not know why it happens since I just want to workerAddr to be set by either channel.  Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
for i:= 0; i < mr.nMap; i++ {   
    go func(jobCount) {
        for {
            var workerAddr string
            Select {
                // get a worker either from registerChannel or from idle channel
                case workerAddr = <- mr.registerChannel:
                case workerAddr = <- mr.idleChannel:
            } 
            // omit the following code
        }
    }(i)
}
```

Comment: `select` is not capitalized. https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5

Comment: @RayfenWindspear Thanks again haha.

Comment: None of the go keywords are capitalized. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you have written `Select` when you should have written `select`.

None of the Go keywords are capitalized, so when the compiler sees a capitalized word, it knows immediately that it's not an expression, and therefore a syntax error.